# Rotate Button On Orientation Changed to Landscape View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am making one Paint application..The button marked with Red circle, I want it to be rotated 90 degree "when orientation is changed to Landscape mode".. Image marked with RED circle is placed on BUTTON.. So should i rotate button or image when orientation changes??

Hope this description will give you idea about my problem.. Thanks..

Please follow this link to see screenshot as i am not allowed to post image..

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/26/screenshot20110712at507.png/

Comment: you only want to change button's position or all the elements on that view ?

Comment: That button plus Two buttons of UNDO & REDO at Left and Right Corner also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the frame of UIButton in the following method as follows:

In .h class

```
IBOutlet UIButton *redButton;
```

And in .m class:

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
         if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
         {
             redButton.frame = CGRectMake(100,50,100,50)
         }
         else 
         {
             redButton.frame = CGRectMake(50,100,100,50)
         }

   return YES;

    }
```

So, you can change the frame of your button as per the requirement.

Comment: for all the class you should have the method: "  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
" And it should return YES; then it will work. Please try it now.

Comment: So, You need to have that mehtod in each and every class which return YES;

Comment: Well I am using Paint application using OpenGL framework so I am not able to detect Orientation on Device..Anyone Knows code for that??

Comment: @patel.rohn: OpenGL ES doesn't disable the possibility to detect orientation changes.

Comment: @AppAspect only in every UIViewController class, not all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do either but I think it would be easier to just flip the image 90 degrees. When your application switches to landscape have a new image, really just the old image turned 90 degrees, and set that as the image for the button. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have thought of it..But how do i Detect Orientation event??? mean in code where do i  put that new image setting Code?

Answer (score 0):

Well thats a sweet deal. Just copy paste the follwing code in your view controller (the one in which you want the buttons to be rotated).

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    return YES;
else {
    return NO;
}}
```

This might give you the idea of your target. Happy Coding..!

Comment: isn't better: return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); ?